Error when display foreign language for the first time
Am I writing a short story, and I feel most comfortable writing with Latex than any rich-text editor. Yet for the first time I have to use two different languages in my story. French as the main language (my native one), and Tamil (since my story takes places in Tamil Nadu).
But I have an issue that only happens once when rendering my pdf:

And the next time I use tamil everything is fine, I don't have any error compiling my project.
I configured my babel as such
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\babelprovide[
    main,
    import,
    language = Default]
    {french}
\babelprovide[import]{tamil}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\babelfont[*tamil]{rm}{Lohit Tamil}
\renewcommand{\FBthinspace}{\FBcolonspace}

My configuration file is way longer, but I only put the babel part, since most of the rest is from a template.
Also I'm using XeTeX, it seems to work fine with luatex, but I have a timeout when trying to compile with luatex on Overleaf
EDIT:
I have a very dirty solution:
I added \phantom{\foreignlanguage{tamil}{தாலுகா}} to correct the glitch of the first occurence, don't know why it happens only on first occurence though, but thank you all for your replies

.Welcome to tex.sx

The font probably does not have some of the glyphs. Can you post what you typed to get the image you posted?

don't use \babelprovide for languages which have an ldf unless you really know what you are doing. as I understand it, it is meant for cases where a full language definition isn't available. maybe that's the case for Tamil, but it surely isn't for French.

@yannis! : I typed this : தாலுகா, in the file it looks like this : \foreignlanguage{tamil}{தாலுகா}

@cfr It is indeed not necessary for french thank you

Is your font quick solution, download Noto Sans Tamil then %NotoSansTamil:mode=harf;color=FF0000; \documentclass{article} \usepackage[french]{babel} \usepackage{fontspec} \babelprovide[     main,     import,     language = Default]     {french} \babelprovide[import]{tamil} \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase} \babelfont[*tamil]{rm}{NotoSansTamil} \renewcommand{\FBthinspace}{\FBcolonspace} \begin{document} \foreignlanguage{tamil}{தாலுகா} \end{document} runs with LuaLaTeX, I had to add fontspec package as well

I run it locally, with overleaf you might need to tell it, where is the font. I dont use it, so I run my example locally. Hope it helps.

This file seems to compile fine both with XeTeX and LuaTeX engines (after copying the font Lohit-Tamil.ttf in the local directory):
\documentclass[a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
\frenchsetup{ThinColonSpace}
\babelprovide[import]{tamil}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\babelfont[*tamil]{rm}{Lohit Tamil}

\begin{document}

Du texte en français: oui!

\begin{otherlanguage}{tamil}
தமிழ்
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}



Yet, when I use \foreignlanguage{tamil}{தாலுகா}} I have this weird glitch, but only the first time I use it, I will try to come up with a solution to make it work on my project with XeTeX. I quite don't understand why it seems that only my project has this glitch. I will also try to use otherlanguage environment to be sure thank you

First, you have a spurious closing brace at the end of your \foreignlanguage command. Second, inserting your \foreignlanguage command (without the last brace) instead of my otherlanguage environment works perfectly with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX on my system. The culprit is probably somewhere else in your template.
